# c++ get output one time in while loop

Tags: c++, time, while-loop

hello i am trying to get the output one time in while loop

```
While(1){
    if( current->tm_hour == 10 && current->tm_min == 0  ){
        Start_Function();
        std::cout <<  "Started" << std::endl;
    }

    if( current->tm_hour == 12 && current->tm_min == 0  ){
        End_Function();
        std::cout <<  "Ended" << std::endl;
    }

    Sleep(5000);
}
```

and i use sleep to refresh every 5 sec

so i want when the current Hour & minut = 10 & 00

it give me output Started and it call the function just one time and it contiune refreshing

Comment: set a bool flag to indicate the function has been called - clear it when the time no longer matches.

Comment: @sje397 Why not make that an answer?

Comment: can you give a example pls, i am still beginner in c++

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: In light of @Joachim Pileborg's comment

> It's not the output that's the problem, it's that the functions are called (and the output printed) multiple times when it shouldn't. – Joachim Pileborg

Alternate solution

```
int hasStarted = 0, hasEnded = 0;
While(1){
if( current->tm_hour == 10 && current->tm_min == 0 && !hasStarted  ){
Start_Function();
    std::cout <<  "Started" << std::endl;
    hasStarted = 1;
}

if( current->tm_hour == 12 && current->tm_min == 0  && !hasEnded ){
End_Function();
    std::cout <<  "Ended" << std::endl;
    hasEnded = 1;
}

Sleep(5000);
}
}
```

The code above will force it to only do each of the operation's once and continue refreshing...

My original comment:

In the command line/terminal as you've foundout the output is printed out continuously. Depending on what operating system you use (window/linux/mac) the solution will be easy or not so easy.

I recommend looking up the `gotoxy()` function

http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/gotoxy

provided by the "conio.h" library for Windows or "ncurses.h" for Linux.

"ncurses.h" doesn't have the `gotoxy()` but it will provide you with a way to do the same.

Comment: It's not the output that's the problem, it's that the functions are called (and the output printed) multiple times when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
bool start_called = false, end_called = false;
While(1){
    if( current->tm_hour == 10 && current->tm_min == 0 && !start_called  ){
        Start_Function();
        std::cout <<  "Started" << std::endl;
        start_called = true;
    } else
        start_called = false;

    if( current->tm_hour == 12 && current->tm_min == 0 && !end_called ){
        End_Function();
        std::cout <<  "Ended" << std::endl;
        end_called = true;
    } else
        end_called = false;

    Sleep(5000);
}
```

You could do it better with functors but that's a little more advanced.

Comment: it still give me multiple output :S but its ok :)

Comment: @beshoyMounir Yep, it calls it once each time the time matches - so once per day. Seemed to make sense to me :) But if you want once and once only then it's just a matter of removing the else clauses.